# Static inner class in lambda expression : NoSuchMethodError access$0

Tags: java, serialization, lambda, inner-classes, nosuchmethoderror

consider following class: with inner static class **Timeline**

```
public class TestClass implements Serializable {

    static class Timeline implements Serializable {

        private final CurrencyReference timelineCurrency;

        public Timeline(CurrencyReference timelineCurrency) {
            super();
            this.timelineCurrency = timelineCurrency;
        }

        public CurrencyReference getTimelineCurrency() {
            return timelineCurrency;
        }

        public void add(Day day, MoneyAmount amount) {

        }

    }

    private final Day minimumDay;
    private final Timeline totalStateTimeline;

    public TestClass(CurrencyReference stateCurrency, Day minimumDay) {
        super();
        totalStateTimeline = new Timeline(stateCurrency);
        this.minimumDay = minimumDay;
    }

    TestClass(Day minimumDay, Timeline totalStateTimeline) {
        super();
        this.minimumDay = minimumDay;
        this.totalStateTimeline = totalStateTimeline;
    }

    public void addConcentrationAmountEvents(Collection<? extends ConcentrationChangeEvent> events,
    Function<? super ConcentrationLimitStateKey, ? extends CurrencyReference> currencyFunction,
    BiFunction<MoneyAmount, CurrencyReference, MoneyAmount> conversionFunction) {
        events.stream().//
        filter(event -> !Decimal.ZERO.equals(event.getAmount().getAmount())).//
        forEach(event -> {
            Day businessDay = event.getDay().before(minimumDay) ? minimumDay : event.getDay();
            totalStateTimeline.add(businessDay, conversionFunction.apply(event.getAmount(), totalStateTimeline.getTimelineCurrency()));
        });
    }

}
```

When the method addConcentrationAmountEvents is executed in unit test it completes successfully without any issue.
on the other hand, when the same is deployed to test environment I get following exception:

```
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)        ...
 13 moreCaused by: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.cache.TestClass$Timeline.access$0(Lcom/cache/TestClass$Timeline;)Lcom/datatype/CurrencyReference;
    at com.cache.TestClass.lambda$1(TestClass.java:221)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1374)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
```

the line (TestClass.java:221) is

```
 totalStateTimeline.add(businessDay, conversionFunction.apply(event.getAmount(), totalStateTimeline.getTimelineCurrency()));
```

At first I was trying  to access the Timeline.timelineCurrency directly, without getter, but in both cases the error is the same. 
Why would I need generated access$0 method if I am accessing the filed via a getter and why this problem does not occur in unit tests?
I greatly appreciate any suggestions.
thank you

Edit:

After decomipiling, I noticed the following:

```
  static /* synthetic */ List access$0(TestClass.Timeline timeline) {
        return timeline.timeline;
    }

    static /* synthetic */ CurrencyReference access$1(TestClass.Timeline timeline) {
        return timeline.timelineCurrency;
    }
```

As you can see the names of the methods are wrong and the method access$1 should have been used. Should I be able to see this in decompiled parent class?

Comment: Are you sure it was compiled correctly? Try decompiling and seeing if the method exists.

Comment: If unit tests (which basically compile all related classes) run without problem, then the actual problem is in your deployment: it wasn't recompiled when you added (or removed, changed, etc.) a lambda expression. Try recompiling classes in environment and check again.

Comment: I did and this method exists. It existed even before, I just changed the lambda expression to use it. As far as I have read the access$ methods are created for non static inner classes to access the parent, and here it seems to be a different case

Comment: the unit tests worked with both versions of the code. I also checked the timestamps on the .class files from the deployed jar and they are in line with the timeline of the change

Comment: After decompiling I just noticed the following:

Comment: 'Static inner' is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 2):

With suggestions from Elite_Dragon1337 and M. Prokhorov I was able to pinpoint the problem. 
Indeed in production a class has been modified manually before that looked like this:
    totalStateTimeline.add(businessDay, conversionFunction.apply(event.getAmount(), totalStateTimeline.timelineCurrency));

so in decompiled code it was referring to

```
 static /* synthetic */ CurrencyReference access$0(TestClass.Timeline timeline) {
        return timeline.timelineCurrency;
    }
```

from the Timeline class

In the meantime , the parent class was modified manually and changed in the jar directly which changed the names of the referenced methods.
My solution to use getter was correct and removed the dependency on synthetic method, but the jar was not correctly deployed (which I was unaware of) so the issue persisted.
Thank you for leading me onto the right path.